# Read bitmap and dispay to a range on a Dialog

Tags: visual-c++

Problem:  can't get image to the screen... ??
I am looking for a methodology that I can work from the camera and a file that I can modify the bitmap using GetDIBits and SetDIBits and write to the screen.

So far from a file to the screen... not working

```
HDC hdcScreen;
HDC hdcWindow;
HDC hdcMemDC = NULL;
HBITMAP hbmScreen = NULL;
BITMAP bmpScreen;

BITMAPFILEHEADER   bmfHeader;    
BITMAPINFOHEADER   bi;
BITMAPINFO bif;




// Retrieve the handle to a display device context for the client 
// area of the window. 
hdcScreen = ::GetDC(NULL);
// hdcWindow = ::GetDC(hWndC);

// Create a compatible DC which is used in a BitBlt from the window DC
hdcMemDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hdcWindow); 

HANDLE hFile = ::CreateFile("c:\\captureqwsx.bmp",
    GENERIC_READ,
    0,
    NULL,
    OPEN_ALWAYS,
    FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);   


DWORD nBytesRead = 0;
ReadFile(hFile, (LPSTR)&bmfHeader, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER), &nBytesRead, NULL);
ReadFile(hFile, (LPSTR)&bi, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER), &nBytesRead, NULL);
//HANDLE hDIB = GlobalAlloc(GHND,dwBmpSize); 
char *lpbitmap;// = (char *)GlobalLock(hDIB); 
DWORD dwBmpSize;// = ((bmpScreen.bmWidth * bi.biBitCount + 31) / 32) * 4 * bmpScreen.bmHeight;
ReadFile(hFile, (LPSTR)lpbitmap, dwBmpSize, &nBytesRead, NULL);




//Close the handle for the file that was created
CloseHandle(hFile);



//CRect rect;
//GetClientRect(&rect);

bif.bmiHeader = bi;

HDC hDC = hdcWindow;


HBITMAP hBitmap;
HDC hMemDC;

hBitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hDC, bi.biWidth, bi.biHeight);
hMemDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hDC);
SetDIBits(hDC, hBitmap, 0, bi.biHeight, lpbitmap, &bif, DIB_RGB_COLORS);
SelectObject(hMemDC, hBitmap);
BitBlt(hDC, 0, 0, bi.biWidth, bi.biHeight, hMemDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

DeleteObject(SelectObject(hMemDC, hBitmap));
DeleteDC(hMemDC);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you retrieve the DC for the entire screen. Is that what you really want?

```
GetDC(NULL);
```

Perhaps you should remove that and uncomment the following line:

```
// hdcWindow = ::GetDC(hWndC);
```

According to posted example, you are calling CreateCompatibleDC() with uninitialized 'hdcWindow' argument.

```
hdcMemDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hdcWindow);
```

After reading BITMAPFILEHEADER and BITMAPINFOHEADER, you should move file pointer to BITMAPFILEHEADER::bfOffBits offest.
Then you should call ReadFile() to read the bitmap itself. Btw, required buffer size is in BITMAPINFOHEADER::biSizeImage.

Since hdcWindow is uninitialized, the hDC remains uninitialized too:

```
hDC = hdcWindow;
```

Did you check the return value of SetDIBits()?

Try to modify the following line:

```
hOldBitmap = SelectObject(hMemDC, hBitmap);
```

Then, after BitBlt():

```
DeleteObject(SelectObject(hMemDC, hOldBitmap));
```

I don't know if this is final solution for your problem, but it's a start.

Answer (score 1):

```
        dcMem.DeleteDC();
        hbmScreen = CreateCompatibleBitmap(dc, m_rectFrame2.right-m_rectFrame2.left, m_rectFrame2.bottom-m_rectFrame2.top);// <-- needed
        dcMem.CreateCompatibleDC(&dc);
        hbmScreen = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(NULL, _T("c:\\captureqwsx.bmp") ,IMAGE_BITMAP,0,0,LR_LOADFROMFILE);
   //for setDiBits    
    SetDIBits(hdcWindow, hbmScreen, 0,  
                  (UINT)bmpScreen.bmHeight,
                  lpbitmap,  
                  (BITMAPINFO *)&bi, DIB_RGB_COLORS);
        dcMem.SelectObject(hbmScreen);
        dc.StretchBlt( 
                   m_rectFrame2.left, m_rectFrame2.top, 
                   m_rectFrame2.right-m_rectFrame2.left,//GetSystemMetrics (SM_CXSCREEN),
                   m_rectFrame2.bottom-m_rectFrame2.top,//GetSystemMetrics (SM_CYSCREEN),
                   &dcMem, 
                   0,0,
                   m_rectFrame2.right-m_rectFrame2.left,//GetSystemMetrics (SM_CXSCREEN),
                   m_rectFrame2.bottom-m_rectFrame2.top,//GetSystemMetrics (SM_CYSCREEN),
                   SRCCOPY);
```